# How to remotely rebuild .NET solution with C#?

Tags: c#, iis

i have .NET project that is a IIS Service, this is on Windows Server2008 R2 Machine.
I have another project that is C# program, that using the IIS Web service,
my question is how can i rebuild solution/project of the Webservice from C# program?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you have source files which should be compiled and then compiled project should be placed to the directory which is used by IIS web application?

If yes, I would recomment to create a powershell script. This script would perform 2 main actions:

1. Compile the project. Use `MSBUILD.exe` utility for that.
2. Copy compiled folder. Use `ROBOCOPY` utility for that.

Then just call this script from your C# code.